Proving a (Representing Utility) Function is Continuous
I sincerely apologize for posting such a long question. The question involves a complicated proof of a theorem in mathematical economics. I feel it will be better for me to state my question first. I will add all related background information afterwards. So here is my question:
I need to prove that a function $\alpha(x)$ is continuous at all $x\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$. Since every point of $\mathbb{R}^L_+$ is a limit point, I could proceed to show that for any sequence $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(x^n)=\alpha(x)$. So, consider a sequence $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$.
Suppose that I can show the sequence $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a convergent subsequence. Moreover, suppose that I can show all convergent subsequences of $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge to $\alpha(x)$. Does this imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(x^n)=\alpha(x)$? If so, why is that?
As you can see, it seems that the proof below says "yes" to the above question. But I am confused, because every convergent subsequence converges to the same point does not necessarily imply the original sequence converges to that point (for example, consider the sequence $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\dots$). I think we should instead prove that every subsequence of the original sequence converges to the same point. But I couldn't figure out how to do that.
Am I missing anything? How should we fix this? Thanks a lot for any help!

As I mentioned in the beginning, the question is from a proof of a theorem in mathematical economics. So let me state the theorem together with its proof in this section. In the next section, I will provide related notations and definitions.

Theorem$\quad$ Suppose that the rational preference relation $\succsim$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^L_+$ is monotone and continuous. Then there exists a continuous utility function $u(x)$ that represents $\succsim$.

Before we prove the theorem, we need a lemma.

Lemma$\quad$ For a monotone, continuous, and rational preference relation $\succsim$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^L_+$, $y\geq x$ implies $y\succsim x$.


Proof of lemma$\quad$ Let $\succsim$ be a monotone, continuous, complete, and transitive preference relation on $X=\mathbb{R}^L_+$. Suppose first that $y\gg x$; that is, $y_i>x_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,L$. Then by the definition of monotonicity, $y\succ x$ and thus $y\succsim x$. Now suppose that $y_i=x_i$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,L\}$ and $y_k>x_k$ for all $k\neq i$. (So $y\geq x$.) Let $\{y^n\}$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^L_+$ such that $y^n_k=y_k$ for $k\neq i$ and $y^n_i=y_i+\frac{1}{n}$. Let $\{x^n\}$ be a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^L_+$ such that $x^n_k=x_k$ for $k\neq i$ and $x^n_i=x_i+\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then for each $n$, $y^n_k = y_k > x_k = x^n_k$ and $y^n_i = y_i + \frac{1}{n} = x_i + \frac{1}{n} > x_i + \frac{1}{n+1} = x^n_i$. Thus $y^n\gg x^n$, and monotonicity implies $y^n\succ x^n$, and so $y^n\succsim x^n$. So we have constructed a sequence of pairs $\{(x^n,y^n)\}$ with $y^n\succsim x^n$ for all $n$, $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$, and $y=\lim_{n\to\infty}y^n$. Then continuity implies $y\succsim x$.

Now we prove the theorem.

Proof$\quad$ We proceed our proof with the help of Figure 1. Denote the diagonal ray in $\mathbb{R}^L_+$ (the locus of vectors with all $L$ components equal) by $Z$. It will be convenient to let $e$ designate the $L$-vector whose elements are all equal to 1. Then $\alpha e\in Z$ for all nonnegative scalars $\alpha\geq0$.
By the above lemma, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$, we have $x\succsim 0$. Also note that for any $\overline{\alpha}$ such that $\overline{\alpha}e\gg x$ (as drawn in the figure), we have $\overline{\alpha}e\succ x$ and so $\overline{\alpha}e\succsim x$ by monotonicity. Then, monotonicity and continuity can then be shown to imply that there is a unique value $\alpha(x)\in[0,\overline{\alpha}]$ such that $\alpha(x)e\sim x$.
Formally, this can be shown as follows: By continuity, the upper and lower contour sets of $x$ are closed. We show that the set $A^+ = \{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_+:\alpha e\succsim x\}$ and $A^- = \{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_+:x\succsim\alpha e\}$ are nonempty and closed. To see the nonemptiness of $A^+$, note that for any $x=(x_1,\dots,x_L)\in\mathbb{R}_+$, we can always choose an $\alpha' = \max\{x_1,\dots,x_L\}+1$, so that $\alpha'e\succ x$. Thus $A^+\neq\emptyset$. To see the nonemptiness of $A^-$, simply pick $\alpha''=0$, so that $x\succsim0=\alpha''e$ would imply $A^-\neq\emptyset$. We now prove the closedness of $A^+$ and $A^-$. Let $\alpha$ be a limit point of $A^+$. Then there exists a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ in $A^+$ such that $\alpha = \lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n$ and $\alpha_ne\succsim x$ for all $n$. Consider the sequence of pairs $\{(x,\alpha_ne)\}$ with $\alpha_ne\succsim x$, $x = \lim_{n\to\infty}x$, and $\alpha e = \lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_ne$. By continuity, we have $\alpha e\succsim x$, so that $\alpha\in A^+$. Hence every limit point of $A^+$ is a point of $A^+$, which means $A^+$ is closed. A similar argument would show that $A^-$ is closed. Finally, not that by completeness of $\succsim$, $\mathbb{R}_+=(A^+\bigcup A^-)$. Then the nonemptiness and closedness of $A^+$ and $A^-$, together with the fact $\mathbb{R}_+$ is connected, imply that $A^+\bigcap A^-\neq\emptyset$. Thus there exists a scalar $\alpha$ such that $\alpha e\sim x$. Furthermore, by monotonicity, $\alpha_1e\sim\alpha_2e$ whenever $\alpha_1>\alpha_2$. Hence there can be at most one scalar satisfying $\alpha e\sim x$. This scalar is $\alpha(x)$.

We now take $\alpha(x)$ as our utility function; that is, we assign a utility value $u(x)=\alpha(x)$ to every $x$. This utility level is also depicted in Figure 1. We need to check two properties of this function: that it represents the preference $\succsim$ (i.e., that $\alpha(x)\geq\alpha(y)$ if and only if $x\succsim y$) and that it is a continuous function.
That $\alpha(x)$ represents preferences follows from its construction. Formally, suppose first that $\alpha(x)\geq\alpha(y)$. Then either $\alpha(x)>\alpha(y)$ or $\alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$. If $\alpha(x)>\alpha(y)$, then $\alpha(x)e = (\alpha(x),\dots,\alpha(x)) \gg (\alpha(y),\dots,\alpha(y)) = \alpha(y)e$. By the monotonicity, this implies that $\alpha(x)e\succ\alpha(y)e$, and so $\alpha(x)e\succsim\alpha(y)e$. If $\alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$, then $\alpha(x)e=(\alpha(x),\dots,\alpha(x)) = (\alpha(y),\dots,\alpha(y))=\alpha(y)e$. The above lemma implies that $\alpha(x)e\succsim\alpha(y)e$. Therefore, $\alpha(x)e\succsim\alpha(y)e$. Since $x\sim\alpha(x)e$ and $y\sim\alpha(y)e$, we have $x\succsim y$. Suppose, on the other hand, that $x\succsim y$. Then $\alpha(x)e\sim x\succsim y\sim\alpha(y)e$. Assume to the contrary that $\alpha(y)>\alpha(x)$. Then $\alpha(y)e\gg\alpha(x)e$, and monotonicity would imply that $y\sim\alpha(y)e\succ\alpha(x)e\sim x$, a contradiction. Therefore, $\alpha(x)\geq\alpha(y)$.

(My question above essentially begins from here:)

(Cont'd) We now argue that $\alpha(x)$ is a continuous function at all $x$. Since every point of $\mathbb{R}^L_+$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}^L_+$, we shall prove for any sequence $\{x^n\}$ with $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(x^n)=\alpha(x)$. Hence consider a sequence $\{x^n\}$ such that $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$.
We note first that the sequence $\{\alpha(x^n)\}$ must have a convergent subsequence. By monotonicity, for any $\epsilon>0$, $\alpha(x')$ lies in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}_+$, $[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$, for all $x'$ such that $\|x'-x\|\leq\epsilon$ (see the figure below). Since $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$, there exists an $N$ such that $\alpha(x^n)$ lies in this compact set for all $n>N$. But any infinite sequence that lies in a compact set must have a convergent subsequence.

What remains is to establish that all convergent subsequences of $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\alpha(x)$. To see this, suppose otherwise: that there is some strictly increasing function $m(\cdot)$ that assigns to each positive integer $n$ a positive integer $m(n)$ and for which the subsequence $\{\alpha(x^{m(n)})\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\alpha'\neq\alpha(x)$. We first show that $\alpha'>\alpha(x)$ leads to a contradiction. To begin, note that monotonicity would then imply that $\alpha'e\succ\alpha(x)e$. Now, let $\hat{\alpha} = \frac{1}{2}[\alpha'+\alpha(x)]$. The point $\hat{\alpha}e$ is the midpoint on $Z$ between $\alpha'e$ and $\alpha(x)e$ (see the second figure). By monotonicity, $\hat{\alpha}e\succ\alpha(x)e$. Now, since $\alpha(x^{m(n)})\to\alpha'>\hat{\alpha}$, there exists an $\overline{N}$ such that for all $n>\overline{N}$, $\alpha(x^{m(n)})>\hat{\alpha}$. Hence, for all such $n$, $x^{m(n)}\sim\alpha(x^{m(n)})e\succ\hat{\alpha}e$ (where the latter relation follows from monotonicity). Because preferences are continuous, this would imply that $x\succsim\hat{\alpha}e$. But since $x\sim\alpha(x)e$, we get $\alpha(x)e\succsim\hat{\alpha}e$, which is a contradiction. The argument ruling out $\alpha'<\alpha(x)$ is similar. Thus, since all convergent subsequences of $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ must converge to $\alpha(x)$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha(x^n)=\alpha(x)$, and we done.


Some related notations and definitions:

Notation$\quad$ $\mathbb{R}^L_+ = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^L:x_l\geq0\ \text{for}\ l=1,\dots,L\right\}$.


Notation$\quad$ Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$ so $x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_N)$. Then
(i) $x\geq y$ means $x_n\geq y_n$ for all $n=1,\dots,N$;
(ii) $x\gg y$ means $x_n>y_n$ for all $n=1,\dots,N$.


Definition$\quad$ The preference relation $\succsim$ on $X$ is rational if it possesses the following two properties:
(i) Completeness. For all $x,y\in X$, we have $x\succsim y$ or $y\succsim x$ (or both).
(ii) Transitivity. For all $x,y,z\in X$, if $x\succsim y$ and $y\succsim z$, then $x\succsim z$.


Definition$\quad$ The preference relation $\succsim$ on $X$ is monotone if $x\in X$ and $y\gg x$ implies $y\succ x$.


Definition$\quad$ The preference relation $\succsim$ on $X$ is continuous if it is preserved under limits. That is, for any sequence of pairs $\{(x^n,y^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x^n\succsim y^n$ for all $n$, $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$, and $y\lim_{n\to\infty}y^n$, we have $x\succsim y$.


Reference$\quad$ Mas-Colell, Andreu, Michael D. Whinston, and Jerry R. Green (1995). Microeconomic Theory. New York: Oxford University Press.

Update (5/13/2024, 9:16 PM EDT)$\quad$ As you can see, the statement of the theorem here as well as the proof I presented in this post is different from the original one (Proposition 3.C.1) in the book Microeconomic Theory. This is because I have revised and corrected certain parts of the original proof. But I couldn't figure out this final step of proving $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\alpha(x)$. As is pointed out by @StevenLandsburg, the idea of proving every subsequence of the original sequence $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ won't work. I would really appreciate it if someone could offer a strategy to fix the proof of the convergence of $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to $\alpha(x)$! Thank you very much!

@StevenLandsburg Thank you so much for your comment! I understand that this might be a little off topic. I post it here because I think the problem itself is quite mathematical. This is essentially Proposition 3.C.1 from Microeconomic Theory by Mas-Colell et al. (I added the reference to the post.) Does it mean that the original proof from the book is wrong? If so, could you please offer a strategy to fix this proof? I sincerely appreciate your help!

This answer is for proving $\alpha(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^L_+$. Before we proceed, we need a proposition:

Proposition$\quad$ Consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ on $X$. Suppose $\{x_n\}$  lies in a compact subset of $X$ for all but finitely many $n$. Then $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ if every convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$.
Proof$\quad$ Assume to the contrary that $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to $x$. Then there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every integer $k$ there is an $n>k$ such that $d(x_n,x)\geq\epsilon$. Thus we get a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $d(x_{n_k},x)\geq\epsilon$ for all positive integer $k$. Since this subsequence lies in a compact subset of $X$ for all but finitely many $k$, it has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_{k_m}}\}$. Since $d(x_{n_{k_m}},x)\geq\epsilon$ for all positive integer $m$ for some $\epsilon>0$, $\{x_{n_{k_m}}\}$ cannot converge to $x$. But $\{x_{n_{k_m}}\}$ is itself an subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ and thus should converge to $x$ by out hypothesis. So we reached a contradiction.

Now we prove the continuity of $\alpha(x)$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. We show that for any $x'\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$ such that $\|x'-x\|\leq\epsilon$, $\alpha(x')\in[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$, where $\alpha_0=0$ and $\alpha_1=\max\{x_1,\dots,x_L\}+\epsilon$. Clearly, $\alpha(x')\geq0$, for otherwise $0\gg\alpha(x')e$ and monotonicity would imply $0\succ\alpha(x')e\sim x'$, contradicting the fact that $x'\succsim0$. Now assume $\alpha(x')>\alpha_1$. Let $x''=(x_1+\epsilon,\dots,x_L+\epsilon)$. Then $\alpha(x')e\gg x''$ and monotonicity would imply that $x'\sim\alpha(x')e\succ x''$. However, $x_i''=x_i+\epsilon\geq x_i'$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,L\}$, becuase otherwise $\|x'-x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^L(x_i'-x_i)^2}>\epsilon$. Then $x''\geq x'$, and the Lemma in your post implies $x''\succsim x'$. So we reached a contradiction. Therefore, for any $x'\in\mathbb{R}^L_+$ such that $\|x'-x\|\leq\epsilon$, $\alpha(x')$ belongs to the compact set $[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$. Since $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon$, and so $\alpha(x^n)\in[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$. That is, the sequence $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ lies in the compact interval $[\alpha_0,\alpha_1]$ for all but finitely many $n$. Hence it has a convergent subsequence.
According to the above proposition, we can finish our proof by showing that all convergent subsequences of $\{\alpha(x^n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge to $\alpha(x)$. Assume to the contrary that there is a subsequence $\{\alpha(x^{n_k})\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converging to $\alpha'\neq\alpha(x)$. We first show that $\alpha'>\alpha(x)$ leads to a contradiction. To begin, note that $\alpha'e\gg\alpha(x)e$, and so monotonicity would imply $\alpha'e\succ\alpha(x)e$. Now let $\hat{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha'+\alpha(x)}{2}$.  Then $\alpha'>\hat{\alpha}$. The point $\hat{\alpha}e$ is the midpoint on $Z$ between $\alpha'e$ and $\alpha(x)e$. Clearly, $\hat{\alpha}e\gg\alpha(x)e$, and so monotonicity implies $\hat{\alpha}e\succ\alpha(x)e$. Now since $\{\alpha(x^{n_k})\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\alpha'>\hat{\alpha}$, it follows that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an integer $\overline{N}$ such that $k\geq\overline{N}$ implies $|\alpha(x^{n_k})-\alpha'|<\epsilon$. If we let $\epsilon=\alpha'-\hat{\alpha}$, then we have $|\alpha(x^{n_k})-\alpha'|<\alpha'-\hat{\alpha}$. If $\alpha(x^{n_k})\geq\alpha'$, then $\alpha(x^{n_k})\geq\alpha'>\hat{\alpha}$. If $\alpha(x^{n_k})<\alpha'$, then $\alpha'-\alpha(x^{n_k})<\alpha'-\hat{\alpha}$, which implies $\alpha(x^{n_k})>\hat{\alpha}$. So $\alpha(x^{n_k})$ is always greater than $\hat{\alpha}$ for $k\geq\overline{N}$. Hence for such $k$, $\alpha(x^{n_k}e)\gg\hat{\alpha}e$, and so $x^{n_k}\sim\alpha(x^{n_k})e\succ\hat{\alpha}e$ by monotonicity. Now consider the sequence of pairs $\{(x^{n_k},\hat{\alpha}e)\}_{k=\overline{N}}^{\infty}$. (Relabeling it if necessary as $\{(x^m,\hat{\alpha}e)\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$.) Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=x$ implies the subsequence $\{x^{n_k}\}_{k=\overline{N}}$ (or $\{x^m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ after relabeling) converges to $x$, and that $x^{n_k}\succsim\hat{\alpha}e$ for all $k\geq\overline{N}$ ($x^m\succsim\hat{\alpha}e$ for all $m$). By continuity, we have $x\succsim\hat{\alpha}e$. However, since $x\sim\alpha(x)e$, we get $\alpha(x)e\succsim\hat{\alpha}e$, contradicting $\hat{\alpha}e\succ\alpha(x)e$. Therefore, $\alpha'\leq\alpha(x)$.
Next we prove that $\alpha'<\alpha(x)$ leads to a contradiction. To begin, note that $\alpha(x)e\gg\alpha'e$, and so monotonicity implies $\alpha(x)e\succ\alpha'e$. Now let $\hat{\alpha} = \frac{\alpha'+\alpha(x)}{2}$. Then $\hat{\alpha}>\alpha'$. The point $\hat{\alpha}e$ is the midpoint on $Z$ between $\alpha'e$ and $\alpha(x)e$. Clearly, $\alpha(x)e\gg\hat{\alpha}e$, and so monotonicity implies $\alpha(x)\succ\hat{\alpha}e$. Now since $\{\alpha(x^{n_k})\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\alpha'<\hat{\alpha}$, it follows that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an integer $\overline{N}$ such that $k\geq\overline{N}$ implies $|\alpha(x^{n_k})-\alpha'|<\epsilon$. If we let $\epsilon=\hat{\alpha}-\alpha'$, then we have $|\alpha(x^{n_k})-\alpha'|<\hat{\alpha}-\alpha'$. If $\alpha(x^{n_k})\geq\alpha'$, then $\alpha(x^{n_k})-\alpha'<\hat{\alpha}-\alpha'$ and so $\alpha(x^{n_k})<\hat{\alpha}$. If $\alpha(x^{n_k})<\alpha'$, then $\hat{\alpha}>\alpha'>\alpha(x^{n_k})$. So $\alpha(x^{n_k})$ is always less than $\hat{\alpha}$ for $k\geq\overline{N}$. Hence for such $k$, $\hat{\alpha}e\gg\alpha(x^{n_k})e$ and so $\hat{\alpha}e\succ\alpha(x^{n_k})e\sim x^{n_k}$ by monotonicity. Now consider the sequence of pairs $\{(x^{n_k},\hat{\alpha}e)\}_{k=\overline{N}}^{\infty}$. (Relabeling it if necessary as $\{(x^m,\hat{\alpha}e)\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$.) Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=x$ implies the subsequence $\{x^{n_k}\}_{k=\overline{N}}^{\infty}$ (or $\{x^m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ after relabeling) converges to $x$, and that $\hat{\alpha}e\succsim x^{n_k}$ for all $k\geq\overline{N}$ (or $\hat{\alpha}e\succsim x^m$ for all $m$). By continuity, we have $\hat{\alpha}\succsim x$. However, since $x\sim\alpha(x)e$, we get $\hat{\alpha}e\succsim\alpha(x)e$, contrdicting $\alpha(x)e\succ\hat{\alpha}e$. Therefore, $\alpha'\geq\alpha(x)$.
In summary, $\alpha'=\alpha(x)$. This completes the proof.

